# Android Programming tutorials - Tutorial 5

Tags: android, commonsware

Hello, I am doing tutorials from book "Android programming tutorials", I am having problems understanding Tutorial 5. This is the main Java class:

```
package tiago.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Now extends Activity {
  List<Restaurant> model = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
  RestaurantAdapter adapter = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurants);

    adapter = new RestaurantAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Restaurant r = new Restaurant();

      EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
      EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addr);

      r.setName(name.getText().toString());
      r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());

      RadioGroup types = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.types);

      switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.sit_down:
          r.setType("sit_down");
          break;

        case R.id.take_out:
          r.setType("take_out");
          break;

        case R.id.delivery:
          r.setType("delivery");
          break;
      }

      adapter.add(r);
    }
  };

  class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
    RestaurantAdapter() {
      super(Now.this, R.layout.row, model);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row = convertView;
      RestaurantHolder holder = null;

      if (row==null) {                          
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        holder = new RestaurantHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
      }
      else {
        holder = (RestaurantHolder) row.getTag();
      }

      holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));

      return(row);
    }
  }

  static class RestaurantHolder {
    private TextView name = null;
    private TextView address = null;
    private ImageView icon = null;

    RestaurantHolder(View row) {
      name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
      address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.address);
      icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateFrom(Restaurant r) {
      name.setText(r.getName());
      address.setText(r.getAddress());

      if (r.getType().equals("sit_down")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_red);
      }
      else if (r.getType().equals("take_out")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_yellow);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_green);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My real doubt at this moment is where is \getView()\ method ever called? This is working, but in code I cannot understand when is it called. If anyone is familiar with this book, please can you provide me a fast explanation about what's happening in this code?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When getView() in ArrayAdapter is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160475/when-getview-in-arrayadapter-is-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getView()` is basically called when something is trying to create the `View` that is associated with an element in that `ArrayAdapter`.

It will return the `View` that is created for the element in the `ArrayAdapter`.

---

A similar question has been asked before, see if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160475/when-getview-in-arrayadapter-is-called) helps you any.

Another great [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) on this subject that may be helpful in explaining what is going on with `Adapaters`.

Comment: Specifically, in the case of this tutorial, the `ListView` is calling `getView()` on your adapter as it needs rows, both to initially populate the list, and to handle when the user scrolls the list.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, so this " super(Now.this, R.layout.row, model);" is trying to create a view right?

So at same time it will call getView() wich is defined on import's? And in my code example that method is overrided to garantee it does what we want when is called??

Thanks for help !

Comment: `super(Now.this, R.layout.row, model);` is basically just initializing your `ArrayAdapter` with the parameters you supplied. Here is a link to the source code for `ArrayAdapter` that will give you a better idea of what `super(...)` is doing. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

Comment: i understand it now :) thanks for all replys, it helped me alot! So getView is overrided on super(Now.this, R.layout.row, model);