# How to Update the ListView with the Latest Message

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently I have the following code to display the Phone Number of the sender from the table.

```
public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
    final String query = "SELECT DISTINCT Sender FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE
            + " GROUP BY Sender";
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Message sender = cursorToMessages(cursor);
        messages.add(sender);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return messages;
}
```

Then I display the results using ListView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messages);

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

    List<Message> values = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllMessages();

    ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

That would display only the sender's number. Now, how do I display the sender's number above the message and the date at the right side using listview?

I want to create the same list like the built in Messaging.

Do I need to create another query to get the latest record based on groupings by sender?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a more complex ListView, showing more data, you are going to need to create your own custom adapter class.

As a quick [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905689/android-programming-tutorials-tutorial-5).

Commonsware has some extremely helpful examples on this subject.

Answer (score -1):

adapterObj.notifyDatasetChanged() method to refresh listview with latest messages.