# Do I have to use ListView with Adapter to make getView() get triggered after calling notifyDataSetChange()?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I want to update the items in the list if items has been updated, but there might be no updates at all.

So my question is: if notifyDataSetChange() method is called but no changing in the adapter, will getView() method get triggered?

Updates:

Does adapter has to be used together with ListView so the getView() can be triggered after notifyDataSetChange() is called? If I manually iterate an adapter and later on call notifyDataSetChange(). Will getView() be called?

Comment: Yes, you pretty much have to use an `Adapter` with a `ListView`. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "manually iterate an adapter", but the `ListView` itself is going to call `getView()` whenever it needs a `View`, including when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for your comments. That is all what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike M. for the comment.

In order to make getView() get triggered after notifyDataSetChange() is called, I have to use Adapter with ListView. Like Mike mentioned, ListView is going to call getView().

This link might be helpful: [When getView() in ArrayAdapter is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160475/when-getview-in-arrayadapter-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

It does trigger getView(), since the view that's reflecting your data needs to get refreshed.

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself

Also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work) which gives a very detailed explanation.